# Is there a name to the search query syntax that Google uses?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

Google has a standard search syntax
e.g.  quotations marks (`"`) for a phrase, a prefix such (`-`) for qualified terms or the use of `OR` between words instead of `AND`.

Sounds like it is a standard with a name.
What is it?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Google's synatx has changed overtime. `+` used to be for mandatory words. This changed with the arrival of Google+. Social tags (`@`) and hashtags (`#`) are also more recent additions.

Answer (score 2):

If Google has a special name for their search syntax, they've never shared it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this link: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en

You can see that even Google just says "Google Search"

Comment: When Google refers to "Google Search" in this context, it is referring to the name of the application that is the Google search engine. It's not assigning this name to the query syntax used.

Comment: _Except for the examples below, Google Search usually ignores punctuation._ Are you sure that they are only talking about the application. Because it's not the whole Application which ignores punctuation.